# Draw NSWindow on one screen only

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

Let's say we have two screen scenario and a `NSWindow`,
positioned at the edge of screen 1.
A part of that of that window is also shown on screen 2.

What I would like to achieve, is to draw the window **only on screen 1** and to not show the rest on screen 2.

The reason for that is that's some kind of a specially behaving mini window, not a usual one.

Is it possible to assign a certain NSScreen to draw the window on, only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two very different approaches:

*Use Mavericks*: What you looking for sounds like the behaviour of Mavericks' "screens have separate spaces" mode. In this mode a window is never drawn on two screens except during drag operations, at other times the window is draw on one screen with any areas protruding onto adjacent screens clipped. So if you can restrict use to 10.9 this may save you some work.

*Borderless Windows*: You can create a borderless non-opaque `NSWindow`, just set the appropriate flags. This is how applications create non-square windows, the visible area of the window is now entirely up to you. Now just clip your drawing to the area on one screen using the standard clipping support. You won't have a standard title bar or controls, unless you emulate them yourself, so you have to implement drag yourself etc. You say you have "*some kind of a specially behaving mini window, not a usual one*" so that may not be an issue.

Comment: Since these windows already are ```NSBorderless``` window, clipping would definitely be a good idea. I'd have to apply the clipping on the ```contentView``` of the window, right?

Comment: @Raffael - That's the idea, or a view you fill the content view with.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I've heard of.

What you could do though is restricting the position of the window e.g. via a `NSWindowDelegate` and `windowDidMove:` to listen to position changes and reposition the window appropriately.